# New contributor has more than 1000 rep

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation, per-site-meta, new-contributor-indicator

[This user](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/users/24113/kcrisman) has 1568 reputation yet is still a new contributor:

[image]

It's probably that [this is the first time they post on meta](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/29937/157643).

Comment: @Catija you may want to add the [tag:status-by-design] tag to the other questions too

Comment: The meta rep is synced with main rep and votes on meta does not affect your rep.